# os.system() and subprocess.call() behave differently

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have a script that launches Scribus with a specific file and automatically runs a Python script inside of Scribus.

I now want to pass further options to the Scribus script, but while doing that, I stumbled on a strange difference between `os.system()` (that I was using before) and `subprocess.call()` (that I'd like to use now, since the call is getting more complex).

The original command is:

```
os.system('scribus -g -py /home/ale/src/bin_etc/scribus-a6-to-a4-pdf.py -pa single -- funktionen.sla')
```

the new one is:

```
file = 'funktionen.sla'
arguments = ['-pa', 'single']

call(['scribus', '-g', '-py', '/home/ale/src/bin_etc/scribus-a6-to-a4-pdf.py'] + arguments + ['--', file])
```

While the first command works correctly (and the `single` command is recognized in the *inner* script), when running the new `call()` command, Scribus tells me that it could not find an open file.

To me, both commands look identical. Can anybody help spot the difference?

P.S.: As a complement, here is the documentation for running Scribus scripts from the command line:

https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Command_line_scripts

Comment: "Scribus tells me that it could not find an open file" please post the exact error message. Also use `check_call` which checks status

Comment: the other difference is the lack of `shell=True` (which must be avoided anyway)

Comment: Ok, I've found the error! While posting this question, I've slightly improved the `call()` and now it does work: the change is: from `+ ['-- '+file]` to `+ ['--', file]`. Sorry, the `call()` command above does work. i will leave the question around for short while and then delete it... (or an admin can delete before if it hurries). Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Ok^2: I've found out why I did not find the error before: `['-- ', file]` (with a space after the second dash does not work (but is of course needed when concatenating the strings...

Comment: I wonder If it's worth to leave this question around to make people aware of the difference betwen `'-- '` and `'--'` when converting a command from `system()` to `call()`...

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments to my question, I did not notice that the question had already the correct code.

The issue was that when you migrate code from `os.system()` to `subprocess.call()`, if you have an *end of options* (`--`) you have to take care that you don't leave spaces around the two dashes: `'-- '` is automatically trimmed by the shell (run by `os.system()` but not by `subprocess.call()`, which will pass along the options as they are and the final program will understand it as another option (named with a space) with the value of the file you intended to read.